# Oxygen XML Author Video embedding- not working when I make a pdf out of the xml

Tags: xml, pdf, video, embed, oxygenxml

I am trying to embed a video in an xml(using Oxygen XML Author).When I convert the xml into pdf, the  video dissapears, and it shows instead something like "???". Did anyone stumbled upon this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The construct for inserting video depends on the XML document type -- DITA, DocBook, TEI -- such as [`object`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/object.html#object) for DITA which corresponds to the HTML `object` element; however, none of the constructs support conversion output in any format except HTML, output in PDF is not possible with Oxygen. For PDF you would want to include a link to a public-facing URL so that anyone who downloads the PDF can view the video without needing to have a copy on their local filesystem.